# is it possible to Use key values within app.config in vs 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to access a key value into the another key in app.config but it does not work.

```
<appSettings>

<add key="KEY1" value="dev.cloud" />

<add key="url" value="https://www.[KEY1].com"/>

</appSettings>
```

I tried ${KEY1} like valumanifest.xml but this does not work in app.config.
am I missing something here ?

Comment: I don't think you can do that in the `<appSettings>` section.  You could write a custom configuration section, but why not simply have the program read the value of "KEY1" from the config, and then build the URL value with that?  Much simpler, IMO.

Comment: @Tim I already did that but I was curious to know that is it possible or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use ConfigurationManager to read settings in the appSettings section.
For example:

```
var key1Val = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KEY1"] // returns the value of KEY1 from appSettings.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the using, then this should work.

```
var Key1 = Settings.Default.KEY1;
```

If you want to know more about the Setting.Default, check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx) out.